# I'm not able install android studio sdk files in my Pop OS

Tags: software-installation, android, pop-os

I have installed android studio in Pop OS. I actually wanted flutter and for that i needed android studio also. i was following the official guide from flutter website for linux. when i launched android studio it needed to install some files as given below

[image: the required files to be installed]

i agreed for terms n conditions and proceeded. but while installing i get the following errors:

> Preparing "Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-linux_x64-10696886.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 270191252 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 270191252 bytes..

> "Install Android Emulator v.32.1.15" failed.
> Preparing "Install Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 34 (revision 10)".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86_64-34_r10.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 1541568459 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 1541568459 bytes..

> "Install Google APIs Intel x86_64 Atom System Image API 34 (revision 10)" failed.
> Preparing "Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 2)".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sources-34_r01.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 45502712 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Sources for Android 34: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 45502712 bytes..

> "Install Sources for Android 34 (revision 2)" failed.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-34-ext7_r02.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 63180079 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform 34: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 63180079 bytes..

> "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 2)" failed.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r34-linux.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 61224257 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Build-Tools 34: Connection closed at byte 4718560. Expected 61224257 bytes..

> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" failed.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.34.0.5".
> Downloading https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r34.0.5-linux.zip

> java.io.IOException: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 6333075 bytes.
> Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Platform-Tools: Connection closed at byte 4456416. Expected 6333075 bytes..

> "Install Android SDK Platform-Tools v.34.0.5" failed.

> Android Studio setup was canceled

I installed all these files manually but the android studio ignored those files and said a similar folder already exists we'll download the content in new directory.

inside android studio it shows the following
[image: if i try to create new file it says this]

[image: sdk managar]

[image: the needed files]

if i try to install the same process repeats